# Android data binding nested ternary on expression

Tags: android, android-databinding

In android's data binding syntax is there anyway to do a nested ternary on the result of an expression without calculating the expression twice:

For the single ternary case I have the following:

```
android:textColor="@{stock.mStockDelta.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) &lt; 0 ?
                   @color/red : @color/green}"
```

I'm wondering if there's a way I can set the color for each one of three compareTo results {-1, 0, 1}  just using the xml?

Answer (score 7):

Possible duplicate ([Switch case in Data Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825459/switch-case-in-data-binding))

For the advanced logic in the data binding, you should put your own logic into the method and call it in the xml

```
android:textColor="@{stock.mStockDelta.getColor}"
```

Do your own logic in the getColor method instead of put a lot of condition in the xml. You should remain your xml fully-readable. Leave the logic flow for the java class.

```
 android:textColor="@{stock.mStockDelta.getColor > 2 ?( stock.mStockDelta.getColor ==3 ? @color/green :@color/colorPrimary): @color/colorAccent }"
```

Comment: You can refer to the answer of RRR suggested.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
android:textColor="@{stock.mStockDelta.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) &lt; 0 ?
               @color/red : (stock.mStockDelta.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) &gt; 0 ? @color/green : @color/blue)}"
```

But this is not recommended, you should put this logic in view model as  George Mount suggested in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825459/switch-case-in-data-binding#comment65036519_38825618)